# How can I make function work with span instead of textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use

```
 <span id="cLeft">10</span>left.</div>
```

instead of

```
 <textarea id="cLeft">10</textarea>left.</div>
```

My function below works fine with `textarea id="cLeft"` but doesn't fire with `span id="cLeft"`. What's wrong with my code?

```
   myTrail.addEventListener('keypress', function countChars() {
        var limitChars = "10";
        var stringChars = document.getElementById("myTrail").value;
        var lengthChars = stringChars.length;
        if (lengthChars <= limitChars) {
            document.getElementById("cLeft").value = limitChars - lengthChars;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myTrail").value = stringChars.substr(0, 10);
        }

});
```

Here is JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pshmM/3/

Comment: You mean you want `<span> ... </span>` not `<span> ... </textarea>` right?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

a `<span>` has no value

```
document.getElementById("cLeft").textContent = limitChars - lengthChars;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `<textarea>` you should alter its value:

```
document.getElementById("cLeft").value = limitChars - lengthChars;
```

But, if you're using a `<span>` it has no value, it instead has content, or in other words:

```
document.getElementById("cLeft").innerHTML = limitChars - lengthChars;
```

`innerHTML` !

Comment: Oh, that's right. I knew that, but somehow I forgot.